# how to create a regex string where you don't know what to escape

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, regex

I have a passwd file with the line containing root being:

```
root:6UZSjeWUui3JQ:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

I want this line to be changed to:

```
root:$1$dog$cNv/OuAd7CMNdrhWsHXAR.:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

This password generated using:

```
hash=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt angus)
```

which has an embedded / character.  So this means I cannot use this sed:

```
sed -e "s/root:.*:0:0:/root:$hash:0:0:/" './test/etc/passwd'
```

I have to change to:

```
sed -e "s|root:.*:0:0:|root:$hash:0:0:|" './test/etc/passwd'
```

otherwise I get this cryptic error:

```
sed -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

But what if the hash generated has an embedded | character?  How would I make this script robust to handle any hash?

Here is my script at present which will fail if a hash has an embedded | character.

eg if call like this:

```
sudo ./justsed.sh angus dog
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $1 || ! $2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: justsed.sh <password> <salt>"
    exit 0
fi

# change salt to random chars for real use
salt=$2

# example: $1$dog$cNv/OuAd7CMNdrhWsHXAR.
hash=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $1)

printf "using the following hash: %s, updating file: %s\n" $hash "./test/etc/passwd"

echo "sed command with escaped /"
# this line works
sed -e 's/root:.*:0:0:/root:$1$dog$cNv\/OuAd7CMNdrhWsHXAR.:0:0:/' './test/etc/passwd'

echo "sed replace text"
sed -e "s|root:.*:0:0:|root:$hash:0:0:|" './test/etc/passwd'
```

Comment: Duplicate on U&L: [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape it before calling `sed`:

```
hash=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $1 | sed 's|/|\\/|g')
sed -e "s|root:.*:0:0:|root:$hash:0:0:|" './test/etc/passwd'
```

But that will break if your hash contains `"`, or `\`, as well as if it contains `&` since sed will read that as "whatever was matched" when the `&` is present on the right hand side of the substitution operator. So you'll need to escape those as well:

```
hash=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $1 | sed -E 's|(["/\@])|\\\1|g')
sed -e "s|root:.*:0:0:|root:$hash:0:0:|" './test/etc/passwd'
```

Finally, if your hash contains `:` that will break the whole thing since that can't be escaped given that it's a separator in the passwd file. So I would add a test for that:

```
if [[ "$hash" =~ /:/ ]];
then
    echo "Invalid password! Choose another"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: How would I test this with an embedded | or "

Comment: @arcomber what do you mean? Just use a string: `hash=$(echo '$1$do"g$cNv/OuAd7CMNdrhWsHXAR' | sed -E 's|(["/])|\\\1|g')`.

Comment: and you need to escape `&` and also `\ `. (e.g. `\n` will break the `s///` command, or if you have `\ ` as last char, it will cause issues obviously).

Comment: @RoVo good point about `\`, thanks. But why escape the `&`?

Comment: `&` is the whole match (like `\0`). ==> `echo "foo" | sed "s/.*/&bar/"` gives `foobar`.